# How to implement the button "Back"

Tags: java, find

So, I need to implement a method with text search in reverse order. I made:

```
public static void findBack(JTextArea TextArea, String searchText) {
    jTextArea = TextArea;
    text = searchText;

    try
    {
        if (endIndex == 0) endIndex = jTextArea.getText().length();
        int select_end = jTextArea.getText().toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase(), endIndex);
        int select_start = select_end > text.length() ? select_end - text.length() : jTextArea.getText().length();
        jTextArea.select(select_start, select_end);
        endIndex = select_end;

        if(select_end == jTextArea.getText().toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(text.toLowerCase()))
        {
            endIndex = text.length();
        }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {}
}
```

But the method doesn't work. Please help me, where is my mistake in the method?
thaks a lot.

Comment: "doesn't work" is as "helpful" as it can get (not). It obviously doesn't work otherwise you'd not ask. But in _what way_ doesn't it work? What do you expect (any example?) and what do you get instead? And did you debug your code already?

Comment: I would like to get the implementation of the button "Search back" as in Notepad or in MS Word. That is, when the word is searched from the end of the text to the beginning

Comment: Have a look at the methods you've already used, i.e. `indexOf()` for forward and `lastIndexOf()` for backward searches. Feed them the correct start indices (store those between calls) and it should work. If you read the JavaDocs you'll notice that you'd need to add the length of the search text to the startindex for forward searches (unless you do it for the first time) and subtract -1 for backward searches (unless you do it for the first time).